# Can't access login, checkout etc. I get 404

Tags: magento-1.9, 404-page, magento1.9.3

I have a second store with a different domain. I created the second store with symlinks. Everything worked fine, till I discovered I can't acces any pages that are using html templates. `register.phtml`, `login.phtml` and so on.

When I click in my store on checkout, login or register. I get an 404 error. Saying:

> The requested URL /checkout/onepage/ was not found on this server

Have anyone experienced this issue? How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake. I had to select this in Direct admin:
Use a symbolic link from private_html to public_html - allows for same data in HTTP and HTTPS.

Because when you go to log in for example, you go to HTTPS. But my private HTML folder was empty. When I activated the symbol link, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

check your document root folder contain .htaccess file and SEO settings in admin is set "Yes"

[image]

Comment: I already had this enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Open your phpmyadmin from your host try once this sql command...

Run this Sql

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin'; UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default'; UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin'; UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN'; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: This didn't work.